# Sender's Sendmail says "stat=Sent" but recipent doesn't receive the message

Tags: sendmail

I am trying to figure out why sendmail is saying that it sends out an email but I actually never get it.

This is from the logs when the email is being sent out:  I have replaced the email address with some fake address and I have also replaced the name of the server with a fake hostname.

The most significant point of this information from the logs is that it shows that the "Message was accepted for delivery".

***Do you guys have any suggestions as to why it seems like the message goes out but I never get the actual email?***

```
Jun  2 14:34:40 server sendmail[9668]: o52IYeSi009668: --- 250 2.0.0 o52IYeSi009668 Message accepted for delivery
Jun  2 14:34:40 server sendmail[9667]: o52IYe9I009667: to=someone@someone.com, ctladdr=rick (500/500), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30058, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (o52IYeSi009668 Message accepted for delivery)
Jun  2 14:34:40 server sendmail[9668]: o52IYeSj009668: <-- QUIT
Jun  2 14:34:40 server sendmail[9668]: o52IYeSj009668: --- 221 2.0.0 server.server.com closing connection
Jun  2 14:34:41 server sendmail[9670]: o52IYeSi009668: SMTP outgoing connect on [192.168.1.9]
Jun  2 14:34:41 server sendmail[9670]: o52IYeSi009668: to=<someone@someone.com>, ctladdr=<someone@server.server.com> (500/500), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=120368, relay=mailhost.worldnet.att.net. [207.115.11.17], dsn=5.1.1, stat=User unknown
Jun  2 14:34:42 server sendmail[9670]: o52IYeSi009668: o52IYgSi009670: DSN: User unknown
Jun  2 14:34:42 server sendmail[9670]: o52IYgSi009670: to=<rick@server.rickrodriguezjr.com>, **delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=local, pri=31625, dsn=2.0.0,** ***stat=Sent*****
```

Comment: need more info. How is your sendmail.cf file configured for starters.

Answer (score 3):

mailhost.worldnet.att.net informs you that the recipient is unknown. What you see as mail sent is the DSN sent to inform you of this fact.